# Wordpress Shortcode associated js not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

I have a plugin that creates a shortcode that outputs a form onto the page. There is nothing overly special about the form its self (just a bunch of html echo'd out). Where I am running into issues is when I need to manipulate that html with js. For some reason if I try to enqueue and register the js, none of the dynamic properties I need the form to have work but if I just put the js directly below the shortcode then everything works as expected. I normally wouldn't care if I had to do this for just esthetic js but I will also need this form to make an ajax call when the the submit button is pressed and I don't know how to do that without properly enqueueing the script. Below is the class for the Form output and the class that will just enqueue all the scripts I need:

```
namespace mmUserPreference;


class Form
{
public function __construct()
{
    add_shortcode('user_preference_form', array($this, 'user_preference_form_shortcode'));
}

public function user_preference_form_shortcode()
{
    //the ../ is to keep the form submit on the first page level
    $output = '<div class="user_preference_form_container">';

    $output .= '<form id="user_preference" method="post">';

    $output .= '<div class="top_nav_up">';
    $output .= '<div class="top_nav_top_row">';
    $output .= '<div class="form_title_up">Manage Your e-Alerts</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="top_nav_up_right">';
    $output .= '<div class="form_submit_up"><input type="submit" value="Save"></div>';
    $output .= '<div class="form_collapse_up"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up rotate" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';


    $output .= '<ul class="tabs_up">';
    $output .= '<li class="tab_link_up current" data-tab="topics">Topics</li>';
    $output .= '<li class="tab_link_up" data-tab="stocks">Stocks</li>';
    $output .= '</ul>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= '<div class="form_content_up">';
    $output .= '<div id="topics" class="tab-content-up current">';
    $output .= '<div class="row_up">';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="stocks_field" value="true"> Stocks</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="us_economy_field" value="true"> U.S. Economy</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="row_up">';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="stock_market_today_field" value="true"> Stock Market Today</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="technology_article_field" value="true"> Technology Article</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="row_up">';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="global_markets_field" value="true"> Global Markets</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="top_news_field" value="true"> Top News</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="row_up">';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="nasdaq_field" value="true"> Nasdaq.com</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="investing_ideas" value="true"> Investing Ideas</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="row_up">';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="oil" value="true"> Oil</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="tech_stocks" value="true"> Tech Stocks</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div id="stocks" class="tab-content-up">';
    $output .= '<div class="row_up">';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="aapl" value="true"> AAPL</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="lmt" value="true"> LMT</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="row_up">';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="ekso" value="true"> EKOS</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="noc" value="true"> NOC</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="row_up">';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="ups" value="true"> UPS</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="tsla" value="true"> TSLA</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="row_up">';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="vz" value="true"> VZ</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="nvda" value="true"> NVDA</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="row_up">';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="awk" value="true"> AWK</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="input_label_up"><input type="checkbox" name="rtn" value="true"> RTN</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    if(isset($_COOKIE['mmp_e'])) {

        $output .= '<input type="hidden"   name="email" value="' .  $_COOKIE['mmp_e'] . '">';

    } else {

        $output .= '<input type="text" name="email" required><br> Please enter the email address you would like these updates to be sent to. <br>';

    }

    $output .= '</form>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    echo $output;
    ?>

    <script>
//            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
//                //for the user preference form tabs
//                $('div.user_preference_form_container    li.tab_link_up').click(function () {
//                    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
//
//                    $('li.tab_link_up').removeClass('current');
//                    $('.tab-content-up').removeClass('current');
//
//                    $(this).addClass('current');
//                    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
//                });
//
//                $('div.form_collapse_up').click(function () {
//                    $('.tabs_up').toggle('slow');
//                    $('.form_content_up').toggle('slow');
//                    $('.form_submit_up').toggle('slow');
//                    $('.form_collapse_up > .fa-chevron-up').toggleClass("down");
//                });
//            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }

}
```

then to enqueue the scripts

```
namespace mmUserPreference;


class loadScripts
{
public function __construct()
{
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'loadScripts'));
}

public function loadScripts()
{
    wp_register_script(
        'user-preference-form-style-js',
        plugins_url('../js/mm-user-preference-form-style.js', __FILE__),
        array('jquery'),
        null,
        false);
    wp_register_script(
        'user-preference-form-submit-js',
        plugins_url('../js/mm-user-preference-form-submit.js', __FILE__),
        array('jquery'),
        null,
        true);
    wp_register_style(
        'user-preference-form-style-css',
        plugins_url('../css/mm-user-preference-form.css', __FILE__)

    );

    wp_enqueue_script('user-preference-form-style-js');
    wp_enqueue_script('user-preference-form-submit-js');
    wp_enqueue_style('user-preference-form-style-css');
}
}
```

Then the main plugin file just looks something like this right now:

```
/*
Plugin Name: ******
Description: *****
Version:     1.0.0
Author:      ******
License:     GPL2
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/

include 'classes/Form.php';
include 'classes/loadScripts.php';

use mmUserPreference\Form;
use mmUserPreference\loadScripts;
use mmUserPreference\sendEmail;
use mmUserPreference\userQuery;

$userPrefScripts = new loadScripts();
$userPrefForm = new Form();
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: On "form-style.js" change the last option from false to true and see what happens. This just ensures its loaded in the footer. At the moment its not.

Comment: yes I normally load js in the footer but was trying to load it in the head in hopes that this would fix the issue but unfortunately it didn't really do anything.

Comment: Ahh ok - do you get any errors in the JS console of your browser?

Comment: I get a couple of 404 errors on my local because its not perfectly configured but I don't believe that would break the js

Comment: When I put it on the staging server which is properly configured (no 404 console errors) I still have trouble getting the JS to work....

Answer (score 1):

So for whatever reason I had to load my scripts at the 'wp_footer' hook in order for my shortcode to be effected by the js ie:

```
add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'loadScripts'));
```